# Is there a way to control the transmit power of a USRP B210 via Gnuradio?

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I want to communicate using two USRPs, but I do not know how to set the transmit power of the sender.

I wang to find a way to control the transmit power of transmiter

Answer (score 0):

You can control both gain and amplitude of the B210 to increase and decrease the transmit power.

I assume that you want to control the absolute power, though (i.e., signal power should be xyz dBm). This is possible with the USRP B210, but it requires you to first manually calibrate the USRP yourself. You can find all the relevant information on the manual: https://uhd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page_power.html